# Why are some Eclipse Android projects greyed out?

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

There are some Android projects that are greyed out that I cannot import into Eclipse. I don't know why.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Are these projects present in Package explorer?

Comment: no,they are in other Folder

Comment: Please check whether these projects are eclipse project or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those Projects are already Existing in your Current Workspace. Check them.

If you don't find them in the eclipse then their root folders might be existed in the Workspace folder. You have to delete them manually from Windows Explorer

Comment: These projects are from the Internet.i downloaded them at the other folder not in the Workspace folder.

Comment: I deleted them in windows explorer and it still has them greyed out when I try to import them.